# How to easy upload content to MySql database in Java using JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I’m beginner and I have problems with using MySql in Java with JDBC.
Can anybody paste a lines of code how to use “SQL UPDATE”. 
Or maybe someone know about some good tutorials to learn it?

My code with mistakes:

```
                    try { 
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING, USERNAME,    PASSWORD); 
        System.out.println("Connected!");
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        String strUpdate = "UPDATE rozchody SET nazwa ='test' ";
        ResultSet ra = st.executeQuery(strUpdate);
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from rozchody");
        while(rs.next()){
            System.out.println("wyswietlam: ");
            String s = rs.getString("nazwa");
            System.out.println(s);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand why people use Java to communicate with a Database. Anybody could easily decompile the program and get username, password, etc. to use the Database. Thereby anybody could `DROP` anything within the Database.

Comment: @Vallentin I guess you haven't worked in real world applications where the database parameters **are not** hardcoded but retrieved from an external resource that can be secured.

Comment: That can be avoided using an encrypted properties file. Just for the sake of discussion what language would you suggest for this purpose ?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza No matter how secured or encrypted a program is you can always decrypt it and decompile it. I always do Database communication through a PHP file, from my server. I'm not sure of what you mean by "real world applications" though my Java programs which contains Database communication as I said before I always do it through a PHP file on my server.

Comment: @Vallentin you can configure components in the application server that store the database connectivity and secure them so even if you decompile and look through all the source code you won't get any bit of the database connectivity params. Of course, this is done in real world applications. Not sure what have you seen. If you do it using PHP, good for you, but don't spread the word that Java is not the right tool only because you don't know how to use it.

Comment: @Piotr if your problem is solved then please accept an answer.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I never said anything about "Java is not the right tool" I said that it would be impossible to 100% secure the Java to Database communication, this also goes for other languages than just Java. As I can see in the code, both the `USERNAME` and the `PASSWORD` for the Database is stored within the program, which is bad. If anybody can get the username and password, then anybody can do "extra" things using them.

Comment: @Vallentin *I don't understand why people use Java to communicate with a Database* this sentence explicitly says *do not use Java for database communication* which is **wrong**. Again, if you don't know how to secure it, don't assume Java cannot do it. While you're right that this application shows a lack of security for hardcoding the database connectivity info, **it doesn't mean** all Java applications are configured like that to work with databases. Believe me, in real world applications **this is not how you do it**.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza While saying Java that was because this is a Java/Database related question. "don't assume Java cannot do it" come on, every program can be decompiled as well as decrypted. "in real world applications this is not how you do it" well I've done it with PHP in a "real world application" as well as game. So yes apparently *someone* does do it that way, and I know other people who do it in the same way as I do, using PHP and not Java or the language they are using.

Comment: @Vallentin you're focusing on an example that shows how not to do it, so your argument is invalid =\. If you're fine using PHP or another language for your database communications, it is fine. But one more time, the fact that you think it is not possible to do this in Java **does not mean** it cannot be accomplished. And one more time, **you can use an external resource to configure database credentials that is decoupled form the application, so you could decompile it as much as you wish but will NEVER find any hint about the database user nor its password**.

Comment: @Vallentin so again, do not spread the word that Java is not good for database communication.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza if the Java program does not contain the username and password for the database, then how does it actually connect to the database? seems weird, because you need to connect to the database and to do that you would need the username and password.

Comment: @Vallentin and Luiggi - As much as I appreciate the banter, it's getting rather long in the tooth now. I suggest moving it to chat if you insist upon flogging a dead horse, otherwise I would let it be.

Comment: @Vallentin again, you can configure the database connection settings in the application server, so the applications will just get the database connection with no info of the credentials stored in the application. The database connection is handled by this external component that can be secured. For more info, refer to: [connection pooling](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/connection-pooling/info) and some examples in appication servers like Tomcat: http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html

Comment: @Vallentin it would be better if you post a question about this topic in order to get more answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For executing UPDATE/INSERT/CREATE statements you should use execute() function of Statement class and not executeQuery().

Corrected code :

```
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD); 
    System.out.println("Connected!");
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    String strUpdate = "UPDATE rozchody SET nazwa ='test' ";
    st.execute(strUpdate); // or use executeUpdate()
```

It will return a boolean value that you can check and proceed.

Answer (score 1):

follow this example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-update-a-record/) but this is essentially it

```
String strUpdate = "UPDATE rozchody SET nazwa ='test'";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(strUpdate);
// execute insert SQL stetement
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Good to know you copy the code in that blog and post it as an answer :). Not even tried to adapt it to OP's needs =\

Comment: Just trying to save him a click.

Comment: If you really try to save a click, post code relevant to the problem, do not just copy/paste code from other site and pass it as ours. For example, there's no `DBUSER` table in OP's problem.

Comment: easy enough change to make. not in no ways trying to claim the code as mine. sorry if it appears that way.

Comment: Well then, next time you post a code that doesn't belong to you, at least give credits to the author.

Comment: the link is right above it, not trying to hide anything

Comment: I know, but the code you just posted was a copy/paste without saying it belongs to mkyong.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to do a UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE on a SQL database, you never receive a resultset.
Use `executeUpdate` instead of `executeQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

Only one `ResultSet` object can be opened for a `Statement`. You're creating two `ResultSet` objects with your UPDATE and then your SELECT statements.

Since UPDATE does not return a `ResultSet`, use `st.execute(strUpdate)`. Then you can retrieve a `ResultSet` with `st.executeQuery("select * from rozchody");`

Your fixed code:

```
try { 
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING, USERNAME,    PASSWORD); 
    System.out.println("Connected!");
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    String strUpdate = "UPDATE rozchody SET nazwa ='test' ";

    //Change this
    st.execute(strUpdate);
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from rozchody");
    //Now you won't get an error opening a new ResultSet

    while(rs.next()){
        System.out.println("wyswietlam: ");
        String s = rs.getString("nazwa");
        System.out.println(s);
    }

} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.err.println(e);
} finally {
    if (conn != null) {
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

Note that while the above will work, it is generally better to use `PreparedStatements` rather than re-using a `Statement` for different executions. This will help prevent SQL injection, and you should read into it once you have a firmer grasp on how the `Statement` object works.